# Download a pdf's file code in php

Tags: php, pdf

```
$path = BASE_URL."/pdf/"; 
$filename= $path.basename($_GET['download_file']);

header("Cache-Control: public");
header("Content-Description: File Transfer");
header('Content-disposition: attachment; 
filename='.basename($filename));
header("Content-Type: application/pdf");
header("Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary");
header('Content-Length: '. filesize($filename));
readfile($filename);
exit;
```

This code works but I'm getting `Error in reading pdf file` when opening the downloaded pdf. In the above code I get the file from the location `http://localhost//eec//pdf/CV_Prabin Mishra.pdf`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`BASE_URL` probably has a slash at the end, so you don't need the extra one:

```
$path = BASE_URL."pdf/";
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't see where you ever set the value of $filename, you set the location of the PDF in $fullPath, but then use $filename to read it out. I think the code should be

```
$path = BASE_URL."/pdf/"; 
$fullPath = $path.basename($_GET['download_file']);

header("Cache-Control: public");
header("Content-Description: File Transfer");
header('Content-disposition: attachment; 
filename='.basename($fullPath));
header("Content-Type: application/pdf");
header("Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary");
header('Content-Length: '. filesize($fullPath));
readfile($fullPath);
exit;
```